# Why does this conversion involving type parameter work?

Tags: c#

From C# in a nutshell

> C#’s cast operator can perform several kinds of conversion, including:
>
> - Numeric conversion
> - Reference conversion
> - Boxing/unboxing conversion
> - Custom conversion (via operator overloading; see Chapter 4)
>
> The decision as to which kind of conversion will take place happens at
>   compile time, based on the known types of the operands. This creates
>   an interesting scenario with generic type parameters, because the
>   precise operand types are unknown at compile time. If this leads to
>   ambiguity, the compiler generates an error.
>
> The most common scenario
>   is when you want to perform a reference conversion:
>
> ```
> StringBuilder Foo<T> (T arg)
> {
>   if (arg is StringBuilder)
>     return (StringBuilder) arg;   // Will not compile
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> Without  knowledge  of  T ’s  actual  type,  **the  compiler  is 
>   concerned  that  you  might have intended this to be a custom
>   conversion.** ...
>
> **A more general solution** is to first cast to  object . This works
>   because conversions to/from  object  are assumed not to be custom
>   conversions, but reference or boxing/ unboxing conversions. In this
>   case,  `StringBuilder`  is a reference type, so it has to be a
>   reference conversion:
>
> ```
> return (StringBuilder) (object) arg;
> ```

1. Why is "the  compiler  is  concerned  that  you  might have intended
   this to be a custom conversion" a problem? Is it because of the
   ambiguity that `(StringBuilder) arg` can be either a reference
   conversion or a custom conversion, depending on what the actual type
   of `arg` will be?
2. In the solution, `(object) arg` can be either a reference conversion
   or a boxing conversion, depending on the actual type of `arg`. Is this an ambiguity, and whyisn't this ambiguity a problem?
3. Is it possible that the actual type of `arg` can't be converted to
   `StringBuilder` directly?

   If yes, how can adding a conversion `(object)` before
   `(StringBuilder)` make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. Because of the `if is` check preceding it, *you* know that at runtime it'll be castable; but the compiler doesn't take that `if is` into account. Anyway "ambiguity" means "I don't know what you want", not "I know what you want and you can't do it with that object". 3. If `arg is StringBuilder`, the type can be converted directly. Adding the conversion works because the compiler says so.

Comment: Thanks. (1) In the original example, how can the compiler think of  `(StringBuilder) arg`   as either a custom conversion or a reference conversion, given that no custom conversion    to `StringBuilder` has been defined? (2)  In the solution, what kind of conversion does the compiler think of `(object) arg`? Does the compiler think it as a reference conversion without possibility of being a boxing conversion?

Comment: To the compiler, as I understand it, it's an attempt to invoke a custom conversion that can't be guaranteed to have been defined, since there's no generic type constraint to say "where there's a custom conversion from T to StringBuilder".

Comment: The compiler can't make any assumptions about what kind of conversion it'll be; T could be anything.

Comment: Thanks.  For (2) does compiler take the hint that `arg is StringBuilder` must be true to reach `return (StringBuilder) (object) arg;`, and thus know that `arg` must have type `StringBuilder` or its subtype and `(object) arg` must be a reference conversion and can't be boxing?

Comment: I'd guess not, because this compiles: `if (arg is StringBuilder)
    return (StringBuilder)(object)arg;
else
    return (StringBuilder)(object)arg;
`