# Why can conversion "(long)(object)" from a type parameter be compiled?

Tags: c#

From C# 5.0 Language Specification:

> The above rules do not permit a direct explicit conversion from an
>   unconstrained type parameter to a non-interface type, which might be
>   surprising. The reason for this rule is to prevent confusion and make
>   the  semantics of such conversions clear. For example, consider the
>   following declaration:
>
> ```
> class X<T> 
> { 
>   public static long F(T t) { 
>     return (long)t;        // Error  
>   } 
> }
> ```
>
> If the direct explicit conversion of `t` to int were permitted, one
>   might easily expect that `X<int>.F(7)` would  return `7L`. However, it
>   would not, because **the standard numeric conversions are only
>   considered when the types  are known to be numeric at binding-time.**
>
> In order to make the semantics clear, the above example must instead 
>   be written:
>
> ```
> class X<T> 
> { 
>   public static long F(T t) { 
>     return (long)(object)t;   // Ok, but will only work when T is long 
>   } 
> }
> ```
>
> **This code will now compile** but executing `X<int>.F(7)` would then
>   throw an exception at run-time, since a boxed int cannot be converted
>   directly to a long.

Why does adding `(object)` make compilation work?

In the first example, if I am correct, `(long)` in `(long)t` means the standard numeric conversion without ambiguity, which requires the actual type of `t` to be a numeric type which can be converted to long by `(long)`. Since there is no guarantee  about the actual type of `t`, the compilation fails.

In the second example,

- Does `(long)` in `(long)(object)t` mean unboxing conversion without being ambiguous with other kind of conversion?
- Does `(long)` in `(long)(object)t` require that `(object)t` be a boxed long? But there is no guarantee that `(object)t` must be a boxed long, so why does the compilation not fail?

Thanks.

Comment: Second question: Compilation succeeds because the compiler allows this "yes, I really, really mean it" special case to allow you to handle cases where you know logically that `t` will be long, but the compiler can't prove that one way or another by static analysis at compile time. And if you're wrong, it throws an exception, and it's your problem. It's not that you **must never cast a string to long, ever, ever, ever**; it's just an exception. The compiler just lends a hand so you don't do it completely by accident.

Comment: Thanks. (1) In the first example, does compiler think of `(long)t`  as the standard numeric conversion only, or maybe as some other kind of conversion such as unboxing? (2) In the second example, does the compiler think of `(long)` in `(long)(object)t` as unboxing conversion only? Does the compiler think of `(object)` in `(long)(object)t` as boxing conversion only, or maybe as some other kind of conversion such as reference conversion?

Comment: I would think that casting object to long is obviously unboxing; the rest, I won't hazard a guess. It might be profitable to compile some test cases and dump the MSIL; that's pretty definitively going to tell you what the compiler thinks about the conversions. There's also a former C# compiler team member who frequents the C# tag here who's very generous with explanations; you may hear from him.

Comment: In example 1, `(long)t` means any valid conversion to `long`, which could include numeric conversions, but also an unboxing conversion.  It’s not legal for `T` because the compiler can’t verify that a legal conversion exists if the source type is unknown.  Example 2 is legal because conversions to and from `object` are legal for any type that `T` could conceivably be.  The only types I can think of that _aren’t_ convertible to/from `object` are pointers, and `T` can’t be a pointer type.

Comment: The `(object)` in `(long)(object)` could be a boxing conversion or a reference conversion.  The actual conversion applied will depend on the generic instantiation.  When specialized for value types, it will be a boxing conversion.  For reference types, a reference conversion.  It will never be a user-defined conversion (custom conversion operator).

Comment: @Mike Thanks. (1) So do you mean that compiler can think `(long)t` and `(object)t` as having one of several possible kinds of conversions? This seems contrary to "The decision as to which kind of conversion will take place happens at compile time, based on the known types of the operands" from C# in a Nutshell. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46355656

Comment: @Mike (2) `(long)t` is  "not legal for T because the compiler can’t verify that a legal conversion exists if the source type is unknown."  This seems contrary to [Ed's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355656/why-does-this-conversion-involving-type-parameter-work?noredirect=1#comment79671276_46355656), which says that the compiler doesn't allow ambiguity in the kind of conversion i.e. "I don't know what you want", and can compile conversion specified without ambiguity, whether it will fail or not at run time i.e. "I know what you want and you can't do it with that object"

Comment: @Tim (1) Not exactly.  Given some value `S s;`, then for some expression `(T) s`, the compiler may _consider_ multiple types of conversions: reference, numeric, unboxing, user-defined.  Which types of conversions are _permissible_ depends on `S` and `T`, but the compiler will choose one _at compile time_.  If either `S` or `T` is a generic parameter, then its type is effectively variable, so the compiler _can’t_ choose a numeric or user-defined conversion.  It can only choose a conversion to/from `object`, because that will be a legal conversion for all types that could be substituted in.

Comment: @Tim (2) while the compiler normally chooses a type of conversion definitively, generic parameters are “sort of” ambiguous.  Conversions on generic parameters are, I believe, emitted as (un)boxing opcodes, but whether (un)boxing actually happens will depend on whether the code is being specialized for value or reference types.  For reference types, there will be a runtime cast like you’d get for any reference conversion.